# How to remove a module from Sitecore Marketplace

Tags: sitecore-marketplace

I happened to create two marketplace modules. One of them was by a mistake and need to be removed.

After uploading module2, I got an email from Sitecore saying it was being reviewed and after 3 weeks it is approved and shows up in discover.

On a suggestion from slack, I emailed `marketplace@sitecore.net` requesting to remove module1 but there was no response.

Also, I have updated the screenshot & about section for module2, but it still doesn't show up.

Can anyone please guide me how to contact Marketplace to have my concerns resolved.

Comment: It can take some time for you get answer from marketplace@sitecore.net particularly holiday season, my experience was a few weeks bases one 1 experience

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should always email `marketplace@sitecore.net` in regards of Sitecore Marketplace.

You might escalate issues by emailing me (mva@sitecore.net) with the details but first please always use the `marketplace@sitecore.net` email address.

Comment: I have emailed you my request. Thank you